# Categories in navigation bar, symphony cms

Tags: php, symphony-cms

i am use a **[symphony cms](http://getsymphony.com/)**, and is really good, but i can't modify the navigation bar.

i like a list with my **categories**, i can list the pages but no the categories or articles.

help me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about using the default Symphony workspace? You can get a table view that shows all the entries in your Categories or Articles sections by hovering over the 'Content' dropdown in the top left of the admin interface and selecting the Categories or Articles section.

This view will list all the entries in the chosen section and allow you to create, edit or delete entries.